# keepalived with --log-file doesnt work

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, keepalived

I have keepalived 2.0.19 running in Ubuntu 20.04.

Trying to add the --log-file= option to DAEMON_ARGS in /etc/default/keepalived results in this.

```
keepalived[454603]: -g requires configure option --enable-log-file
```

But if i also add --enable-log-file i get this (too)

```
keepalived[454603]: Unknown option --enable-log-file
```

The man-page doesnt mention --enable-log-file. And if i look at output of 'keepalived --help' it actually doesnt mention either of those options:)

Has anyone used logging (directly) to file in v2.0.x ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using upstream version of keepalived, this option is disabled by default as ChangeLog shows https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/blob/master/ChangeLog#L1793 take a look on https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/blob/master/configure.ac#L265

What you can do it is build keepalived from source with

`./configure --enable-log-file`

Hope this will help.